# Which image is being used as reference in ARSceneView?

Tags: swift, arkit

I am currently making an AR app that uses image tracking.
I want it to have 2 images in the reference images folder (Image A: ~670x210, and Image B: ~1123x794).

How do I check which image is the camera detecting?
For example, if the camera is seeing Image A - I want to make a plane twice the size of the physical object, if it's seeing Image B - I want to make the plane the same size as the physical object.

Here's a snippet of my code, if needed:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

        if let trackedImage = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "ARpaperImage", bundle: Bundle.main) {

            configuration.trackingImages = trackedImage
            configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 1

        }

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }


    // MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

        let node = SCNNode()

        if let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor {


            let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
            plane.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0,5)

            let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)

            planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

            node.addChildNode(planeNode)

        }

        return node

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ARReferenceImage` has a `name` property which you can use to determine which `ReferenceImage` has been detected which is simply:

> A descriptive name for the image

As such when you put your `ARReferenceImages` into your resource bundle you can and (probably already have) given them a name e.g:

[image]

You can the use these names within the following delegate callback to handle your requirements.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

As such lets assume we have two `ARReferenceImages` called Brown and Choco. Using these names we can then create logic to display different content e.g:

```
  //-------------------------
  //MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
  //-------------------------

  extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

      //1. Check We Have Detected An ARImageAnchor
      guard let validAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor, let referenceImageName = validAnchor.referenceImage.name else { return }

      //2. Get The Physical Size Of The Reference Image (This Is Specificed When You Create Your Target In The ARResource Bundle)
      let physicalSizeOfReferenceImage = CGSize(width: validAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: validAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)

      ///3. Log The Data For Debugging Purposes
      print("""
        Detected ARAnchorID = \(validAnchor.identifier)
        Detected Reference Image Name = \(referenceImageName)
        Detected Reference Image Physical Size = (width) \(physicalSizeOfReferenceImage.width),
        Detected Reference Image Physical Size = (height) \(physicalSizeOfReferenceImage.height)
        """)


      //4. Perform Instanciation & Other Login Based On The Reference Image Detected
      if referenceImageName == "Brown"{

        node.addChildNode(planeNodeOfSize(CGSize(width: physicalSizeOfReferenceImage.width * 2, height: physicalSizeOfReferenceImage.height * 2)))

      }else if referenceImageName == "Choco"{

        node.addChildNode(planeNodeOfSize(CGSize(width: physicalSizeOfReferenceImage.width, height: physicalSizeOfReferenceImage.height)))

      }
    }

    /// Generates An SCNNode With An SCNPlaneGeometry Of A Specified Width & Height
    ///
    /// - Parameter size: CGSize
    /// - Returns: SCNNode
    func planeNodeOfSize(_ size: CGSize) -> SCNNode{

      //1. Create An SCNPlane Of Our Chosen Size
      let planeNode = SCNNode()
      let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: size.width, height: size.height )
      planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
      planeNode.opacity = 0.25
      planeNode.geometry = planeGeometry

      //2. Rotate The PlaneNode To Horizontal
      planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi/2

      //3. Return Our Node
      return planeNode
    }

  }
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for! :)